# Excel Converting Rows to Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Input table is

```
Project ID  Project
A   1
A   2
A   3
B   4
B   5
B   6
B   7
C   8
C   9
```

Output Table

```
A   B   C
1   4   8
2   5   9
3   6   
    7
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: How large is the dataset? I think a pivot table may help here...

Answer (score 1):

First place your column headers in row #1 like:

[image]

Then run this short macro:

```
Sub FillColumns()
   Dim i As Long, N As Long, M As Long
   Dim r As Range, v As String
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 2 To N
      v = Cells(i, "A").Value
      Set r = Range("A1").EntireRow.Find(After:=Range("C1"), What:=v)
      c = r.Column
      M = Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row + 1
      Cells(M, c).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
   Next i
End Sub
```

To produce:

[image]

The macro does **not** require either column **A** or **B** to be sorted.

Answer (score -1):

As @Burgi posted in his comment, easiest thing here is to create a PivotTable.

Select the data you want, then select PivotTable from your ribbon. Then set your PROJECT ID row as your columns and project ID as your rows. This will tell you how many of each project A1, A2, A3 you have.

[Excelisfun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2cIAIJAEWA&list=PLDF4390866B480CD2) is a good place to start for more info :)

Comment: "This will tell you how many of each project A1, A2, A3 you have", yes, that's right, however the question is how to list them, not only get their coumt.

Comment: ah, I didn't quite understand the question! Doubleclicking on the relevant result would pull the data into a usable spreadsheet, but this is obviously far more labour intensive...